# preloader not working online

Tags: javascript, html, css, preloader

I am using a preloader for my website. I simply designed it using CSS and coded the logic to hide the preloader when the website gets completely loaded.
The whole thing works on my local machine but when i put it online it doesn't work.

This is the link to the website : http://deepanshubatra.tk (Use google chrome please)

I am mentioning the HTML,CSS and javascript code:

**CSS:**

```
 div#preloader { position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 999; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: visible; background: #333 url('http://files.mimoymima.com/images/loading.gif') no-repeat center center; }
```

**Javascript**

```
<script > 

  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  

// site preloader -- also uncomment the div in the header and the css style           for #preloader
$(window).load(function(){
$('#preloader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();});
});

});

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="preloader"></div>
```

Comment: Your jquery doesnt load and i cant seem to find it in your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in console:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>` to your `head` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The error that is in the console on the page is `jQuery is not defined`. So you need to load jQuery in your scripts. Here is how you can use it with CDN:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

Add HTML inside the body.

```
<div class="se-pre-con">
<img src="../images/logo-02.svg">
</div>
```

Add this CSS Code:

```
.se-pre-con {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
div.se-pre-con img{
    max-width: 300px;
    top: 20%;
    position: relative;
}
div.se-pre-con.highlighted{
    display:none;
}
```

And this jQuery code in the footer:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(this).addClass('highlighted');
        setTimeout(function () {
            jQuery('.se-pre-con').addClass('highlighted');
        }, 2000);});
    </script>
```